# How to better preprocess images for a better deep learning result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

We are experimenting with applying a convolutional neural network to classify good surfaces and surfaces with defects.

The good and bad images are mostly like the following:

Good ones:

[image]
[image]

Bad ones:

[image]
[image]

1. The image is relatively big (Height:800 pixels, width: 500 pixels)
2. The defect very **local** and **small** relative to image
3. The background is very **noisy**
4. The deep learning (6 x conv+pooling -> flatten -> dense64-> dense32) result is very bad 
   (perhaps due to limited Bad samples and very small defect pattern)
5. There are other defect patterns like very **subtle** scratches, residuals and stains, etc., which is one of the main reasons that we want to use deep learning instead of specific feature engineering.
6. We can and are willing to accumulate more images of defects.

So the question are:

1. Is deep learning even an appropriate tool for defect detection like this in practice.
2. If yes, how can we adapt or pre-process the images to the formats that the deep learning models can really work with. (Could we apply some known filters to make the background much less noisy?)
3. If no, what are other practical techniques that can be used other than deep models.
   Will things like template matching or anything else actually be a fit for this type of problems?

---

Update:
Very good idea to come up with an explicit circular stripes checker.
It might be directly used to check where the pattern is disturbed or be used as a pre-processing step for deep learning.

---

Update:
A more subtle pattern 'scratch'.
There is a scratch starting from the bottom of the fan area going up and a little to the right.

[image]

Comment: Could you try to handcraft a detection algorithm that is explicitly checking the circular stripes? Where this pattern is disturbed, there could be a defect. If this alone is insufficient, you could think of using that step as preprocessing to align the images such that the proposed artifact is at the center for further processing.

Comment: Can you also show one of the more "subtle" examples?

Comment: I will upload the subtle ones soon. @Acro Bast

Comment: out of curiosity: what approach was successful?

Comment: @ArcoBast, Unet model family are the most promising ones for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is deep learning even an appropriate tool for defect detection like
>   this in practice.

Deep learning certainly is a possibility that promises to be universal. In general, it should rather be the last resort than the first approach. Downsides include:

- It is difficult to include prior knowledge.
- You therefore need an extreme amount of data to train the classifier for the general case.
- If you succeed, the model is opaque. It might depend on subtle properties, which cause it to fail if the manufacturing process is changed in the slightest way and there is no easy way to fix it.

> If yes, how can we adapt or pre-process the images to the formats that
>   the deep learning models can really work with. (Could we apply some
>   known filters to make the background much less noisy?)

Independent of the classifier you eventually decide to use, preprocessing should be optimal.

**Illumination**: The illumination is uneven. I'd suggest to define a region of interested, in which the illumination is bright enough to see something. I'd suggest to calculate the average intensity over many images and use this to normalize the brightness. The result would be an image cropped to the region of interest, where the illumination is homogenous.

**Circular stripes**: In the images you show, as the stripes are circular, their orientation depends on the position in the image. I would suggest to use a transformation, which transforms the region of interest (fraction of a circle) into a trapezoid, where each stripe is horizontal and the length of each stripe is retained.

> If no, what are other practical techniques that can be used other than
>   deep models. Will things like template matching or anything else
>   actually be a fit for this type of problems?

Rather than identifying defects, you could try identifying the intact structure, which has relatively constant properties. (This would be the circular stripes checker that I have suggested in the comment). Here, one obvious thing to test would be a 2D fourier transformation at each pixel within an image preprocessed as described above. If the stripes are intact, you should see that the frequency of intensity change is much lower in horizontal than in vertical direction. I would just plot these two quantities for many "good" and "bad" pixels and check, whether that might already allow some classification.

If you can preselect possible defects with that method, you could then crop out a small image and subject it to deep learning or whatever other method you want to use.